CG Trader .blend Model shows textures incorrectly
I am fairly new to Blender and tried watching different tutorials, searched this and other forums but can't put my finger on my problem. I am probably missing something fairly basic.
What is my problem
I bought a model from CG Trader (https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/vehicle/truck/piaggio-ape-v-curve-food-track-049c5dd5-8178-4a97-ad07-be610af33858) which includes a .blend file. Through "Find missing files" all textures were imported but it looks like this on the left. Qw you can see the texture is mapped wrong.

The front part of the tricycle and the back part are separate but when I go into "Texture Paint" mode it looks like this on the right. Hence my assumption that for the texture the two parts of the model are somehow linked.
What would help me
Of course the dream would be to get an answer which allows me to have the model look like as in the preview on CG Trader. But what would also help if someone could help me understand what I need to learn (and in which other answers I can read up) in order for me to fix the problem on my own. Do I need a deep dive in UV Mapping, Vertex Groups, Normals... I am a bit lost.
Thank you so much!

If you encounter the issue of having the purple texture showing up instead of another one :
When using the solid view's "texture" color setting, the texture shown in the viewport is the latest selected texture in the shader tree.
To fix this, you just need to open the shader editor, select the concerned object in the viewport, and then select the image texture node containing the color texture.
If UVs aren't used properly, perhaps the model have multiple UVs and the shader isn't using them correctly.
In the shader editor, you can add a UV Map node, plug it to the vector socket of the image texture node, and select the uv map that works for that texture.
That being said: your model isn't made for Blender natively. If some specific mapping techniques were used other than UVs, it might be hard to reproduce it, if at all. Though in this case, this should be brought up to the author. It doesn't sound fair for a paid product to be dysfunctional beyond simple fixes out of the box.
